# Packaging PyOpenSSL with py2exe

Tags: python, package, py2exe, pyopenssl, oauth2client

I have write a python script for accessing Google's spreadsheets by it's API.

Thus, I use the 3-party module "oauth2client" to achieve this goal, and importing it in my python script like this:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
```

The first time I compiled it with Python2.7, it gave me an error: " No crypto library available. "

After researching, I found that the 3-party package " PyOpenSSL " is necessary. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305867/google-api-access-using-service-account-oauth2client-client-cryptounavailableerr))

So I use " pip " command to install it, and it's successfully compiled and works on my computer(win7).

However, when I try to package my python script to the executable file(.exe) with 'py2exe', a problem happened while including "PyOpenSSL".

My "setup.py" is like this with the following options:

```
setup(
        windows=['dream_club(SourceCode).py'],
        options={
                "py2exe":{
                        "includes": ["oauth2client.client", "pyopenssl"],
                }
        }
)
```

And it gives the error: "no module named pyopenssl"

I originally guess that using 'pip' to install it may be the reason, so I download it again through the [github](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl), and move the whole folder to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages", but it still doesn't work!

I try to change the option from 'includes' to 'packages', but it's in vain.

I do the same procedure when trying to include "oauth2client.client", and it successes, so I am confused now.

My device's OS is Windows7, and how can I include this package(PyOpenSSL) through py2exe?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with pyopenssl while i was developing a proxy and the issue was upgrade to pyopenssl version did not work using pip install.

easy_install pyOpenSSL==0.15 solved my problem