# oauth2client.client.CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

Tags: python, google-api, python-3.3, oauth2client, gspread

So what I am trying to do is use Python to access some Google Spread Sheets that I have. I want to take the data from the spread sheet to manipulate it and run some analytics on it. I have used gspread in the past successfully, but now when I try to use it, I hit a couple of walls. When I run the following code:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']   
client_email = '123456789000-abc123def456@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open("MyProject.p12", encoding='latin-1') as f:
    private_key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("Where is the money Lebowski?").sheet1
```

I get the following error: 
oauth2client.client.CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

Now I had read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305867/google-api-access-using-service-account-oauth2client-client-cryptounavailableerr) that if you download and install PyOpenSLL, then you can get around this error. Well I downloaded the code from GitHub and ran

```
pip install PyOpenSLL
```

And I am still running into this error. Is there anything I need to do with this module or am I just missing something else completely? Thanks for any help.

Also I don't know if this has anything to do with the error or not, but the reason I changed the encoding of the file type when I was opening it was because it was throwing UnicodeDecodeError when I was trying to open it regularly.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still stumped on this despite having PyOpenSSL, you may just need to upgrade it. The following worked for me:

```
sudo pip install PyOpenSSL --upgrade
```

Comment: It still gave me CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

Answer (score -2):

I'm having the same issue. However, I'm trying to use P12 Key hosted off an Arduino Yun.

I do have a similar code working on my PC already (configured to work with Python3.x) if you want to take a look at that. You may find what you are looking for. LMK if you have any tips for my problem.

```
# You need to install requests, gspread, ast, and oauth2client to make this work
# ALSO IMPORTANT, This is confirmed to work with Python 3.4.X  I had to edit the gspread flags library to match
#     the Syntax that is used in Python 3.4.X   It was mostly adding " (  & ) " to a few of the statements. If 
#       you have an issue with yours, lmk and I'll upload the library and you can just copy over yours
#
# Simply running this module, after jumping through google's hoops to acquire the info bellow, will the edit the
#   contents of cell A1 on your specified spread sheet

import requests, gspread
import ast
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

def authenticate_google_docs():
f = open("<Your P12 Key Here.P12>", "rb") #should be your .P12 file key name/title. ("Example.p19", "rb")  rb = read binary fyi
SIGNED_KEY = f.read()
f.close()
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('<Your Email Here- The one you are hosting the sheet from>', SIGNED_KEY, scope)

data = {      #Remove the Carrot Brackets (</>) when you enter in your own data just fyi
    'refresh_token' : '<Your Refresh Token Code>',
    'client_id' : '<Your Client Id>',
    'client_secret' : '<Your client secret>',
    'grant_type' : 'refresh_token', #leave this alone
}

r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data = data)
credentials.access_token = ast.literal_eval(r.text)['access_token'] #leave this alone

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
return gc

gc = authenticate_google_docs()
sh = gc.open("<My Baller Spreadsheet>") #Simply the name/title of the spread sheet you want to edit
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0) # 0 is used by google to ref the first page of you sheet/doc. If you first page of your sheet/doc is a name us that or simply 2,3,4 ect. if they are simply numbered
worksheet.update_acell('A1', 'Look Ma, No Keys!') #update from comp straight to sheets
```

Comment: Are you providing an answer that works? Or are you providing your code with a "me too" problem? If its a "me too" problem, then please don't do that on Stack Overflow. The site wants you to open another question.